# Write edited contents of file to stdout

Tags: command-line, encryption, gedit, text-editor

I need a visual text editor that can be used as follows - the example will not work but illustrates the point.

```
gpg2 -d x.gpg | gedit -w - | gpg2 -e -o x.gpg
```

This command will allow me to decrypt a file, edit it and re-encrypt it without the file ever existing on disk in unencrypted form. The problem is to find an editor that can save the edited contents to stdout. The only editor I could find is ed which is very unfriendly to use. I would much prefer a visual editor. Is there an editor that can do this, or alternatively can decrypt and encrypt files within the editor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`vipe`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/vipe.1.html) to edit pipelines:

```
SYNOPSIS
       command1 | vipe | command2

DESCRIPTION
       vipe allows you to run your editor in the middle of a unix pipeline and
       edit the data that is being piped between programs. Your editor will
       have the full data being piped from command1 loaded into it, and when
       you save, that data will be piped into command2.

ENVIRONMENT VARIABLES
       EDITOR
           Editor to use.
```

The trick in using graphical editors is to ensure that it doesn't fork off and start a detached process. For example, to use GVim:

```
gpg2 -d x.gpg | EDITOR='gvim -f' vipe | gpg2 -e -o x.gpg
```

I expect you'd need to use the `-s` option with `gedit`:

```
-s, --standalone
      Run gedit in standalone mode.
```

So:

```
gpg2 -d x.gpg | EDITOR='gedit -s' vipe | gpg2 -e -o x.gpg
```

Alternatively, you could try [this plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/gnupg.vim) with Vim.

Comment: Vipe does the job perfectly.

Comment: @Jonathan well, technically, the file could exist on disk while you're editing it. `vipe` saves the output to a file in `/tmp` while running the editor. `/tmp` could be a tmpfs, but I suppose it still defeats the purpose.